# How to make new row every 4 column in phpword and Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, loops, phpword

This is my code, it give result if columns are 3 it will make new row but not for multiple 3.

```
    foreach ($tampil_data as $key=>$tampildata) {
        $table->addCell(2000)->addText(htmlspecialchars($tampil_data[$key]->elektronik_nama));   //load data
        if($key==3){
            $table->addRow(); //make new row
        }
    }
```

i want to make table every have 3 column or multiple of 3, it makes new row. How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `$key` as a counter because value of key may vary. You need to use 1 temporary variable.
You can try this:

```
$temp_count = 1; 
foreach ($tampil_data as $key=>$tampildata) {
  $table->addCell(2000)->addText(htmlspecialchars($tampil_data[$key]->elektronik_nama));   //load data
    if($temp_count == 3){
        $table->addRow(); //make new row
        temp_count = 0;    //Reset your temporary variable.
    }
  $temp_count++;
}
```

Comment: Yes. It is what i want. Thank you @yash

Answer (score 2):

Use modulo for 3 to check if it is a multiple

```
if($key%3 == 0){
  $table->addRow(); //make new row
}
```

Comment: no. if your functions for adding columns and rows are correct then it should have no problem working

Comment: I think, it'w will work if not using load data mysql. But i don't know something wrong in my code.